# Бот, предлагающий новости в паблики

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Делаю бота для vk.com, который предлагает пост в паблики из списка.

Делаю на python, использую библиотеку **vk_api** для него.
Бот по логину и паролю авторизируется под моим аккаунтом и все выглядит, будто это я - реальный человек (должно выглядеть).

[image: Стрелочка показывает на шестеренку]

Проблема в том, что у предложенной новости появляется вот такая шестеренка, при нажатии на которую происходит переход на вк приложение, с помощью которого данная библиотека(**vk_api**) и работает.

**Мой вопрос:** как убрать эту шестеренку, чтобы выглядело будто это я самолично предложил данную новость?

---

Можно сделать через silenum чтобы бот сам жмакал все кнопки и в каждый паблик заходил и сам предлагал. Меня же интересует как это сделать средствами api, может дело в том, что либа vk_api использует standalone приложение

если что-то непонятно вот код, может что-то прояснит
https://github.com/mamsmotri/vk-promotion/blob/master/vk-promotion.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

через API без нее опубликовать никак не получится. Шестеренка как раз отражает то, что запись размещена средствами API. Единственное, можно использовать APPID приложения android или iOS, чтобы была их иконка.